# FLUTTER FIREBASE Acessar dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebase, flutter, firestore

algúem consegue me ajudar a descobrir esse erro? Preciso imprimir do drop apenas o "nome", mas está imprimindo o id do documento "5A18P1tDPvFOu8cAc5ki".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CODE HERE!

```
   StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("paciente").where("nome").snapshots(),
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                if (!snapshot.hasData){
                                  Text("Loading");
                                }else{
                                  List<DropdownMenuItem> currencyItems = [];
                                  for (int i = 0 ; i < snapshot.data.docs.length ; i++){
                                    DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];
                                    currencyItems.add(
                                      DropdownMenuItem(
                                          child: Text (
                                            snap.id,
                                          ),
                                        value: "${snap.id}",
                                      )
                                    );
                                  }

                                  return Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Icon(Icons.person, size: 25.0,),
                                      SizedBox(width: 50),
                                      DropdownButton(
                                        items: currencyItems,
                                        onChanged: (currencyValue){
                                          final snackBar = SnackBar(
                                            content: Text(
                                              'Paciente $currencyValue',
                                            ),
                                          );

                                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                                          setState(() {
                                            selectedCurrencyPaciente = currencyValue;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        value: selectedCurrencyPaciente,
                                        isExpanded: false,
                                        hint: new Text(
                                          "Paciente"
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                }
                              },
                            ),
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você fez quase tudo certo, só faltou pegar os dados do documento.

Ao invés de:

```
DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];
currencyItems.add(
  DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text (
        snap.id,
      ),
    value: "${snap.id}",
  )
);
```

Faça assim:

```
DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];
final String nome = snap.data()["nome"];
currencyItems.add(
  DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text (
        nome,
      ),
    value: nome,
  )
);
```

### Explicação

Você primeiro pega todos os documentos e com isso cria um loop, passando documento por documento.
Com isso você terá acesso aos dados do documento, só que você estava pegando apenas o ID do mesmo, para acessar seus dados, é necessário chamar o `snapshot.data()`.

Feito isso você vai ter acesso à um `Map<String, dynamic>` com todos os dados que precisa.

Aconselho você criar uma classe para mapear esse *Map* e faciliar seu código e ficar mais limpo, por exemplo:

Ao invés de fazer:

```
final String nome = snap.data()["nome"];
final String endereco = snap.data()["endereco"];
```

Poderia ser:

```
Usuario usuario = Usuario.fromJson(snap.data());
String nome = usuario.nome;
String endereco = usuario.endereco.
```

[Descomplicando JSON em Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-comunidade-br/descomplicando-o-json-em-flutter-47e12b87753b)

Código completo:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("paciente").where("nome").snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData){
      Text("Loading");
    }else{
      List<DropdownMenuItem> currencyItems = [];
      for (int i = 0 ; i < snapshot.data.docs.length ; i++){
        DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];
        Map<String, dynamic> data = snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        final String nome = data["author"];
        currencyItems.add(
          DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text (
                nome,
              ),
            value: nome,
          )
        );
      }

      return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.person, size: 25.0,),
          SizedBox(width: 50),
          DropdownButton(
            items: currencyItems,
            onChanged: (currencyValue){
              final snackBar = SnackBar(
                content: Text(
                  'Paciente $currencyValue',
                ),
              );

              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
            },
            value: 1,
            isExpanded: false,
            hint: new Text(
              "Paciente"
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: Fiz como você disse Matheus e está dando um pequeno erro: "error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'."

Comment: @gleon estranho... Qual sua versão do _Firebase_?

Comment: Alterei minha resposta, veja se agora funciona... Faz um tempo que não utilizo o Firebase e mudou bastante hahaha

Comment: Ainda não funcionou =( Alterei essa linha: final String nome = data["nome"]; , mas seguiu dando erro.      There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: 1. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 882 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'

Comment: Certo, mas agora esse erro que você está tendo já é outra coisa... O seu _Dropdown_ está com valores duplicados. Se você possuí itens com o mesmo "nome", vai precisar então mudar o que a propriedade `value` recebe, pois essa propriedade não pode ter valores repetidos